# How to run IPython Notebooks stored at any location

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I know that the IPython Notebook expects to have a notebook directory and that this can be set at startup with `--notebook-dir`. But is it possible to run a notebook stored at any location without first importing/copying it to this directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021853/multiple-directories-and-or-subdirectories-in-ipython-notebook-session >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start another server if you are using 1.0/1.1. this will be solved in 2.0 that allow you to browse your hard-drive.