# Ipython notebook on remote server doesnot display folders in current directories in the browser

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Ipython based on [tutorial](http://calebmadrigal.com/ipython-notebook-vps/) in my Digital Ocean server.

However, when I try to access via browser, it displays the current directory files as specified in the ipython_notebook_config.py file. It does not show any folders in that directory.

Is there any way, I could view the sub-folders as it helps to create projects neat and in different folders within the structure.

I know a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021853/multiple-directories-and-or-subdirectories-in-ipython-notebook-session) was raised earlier. I guess it had already implemented in the current version.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7, ipython 1.2.1